# GHUnit sumbols for arm64 missing

Tags: ios, unit-testing, gh-unit

I try to run GHUnit on the device and receive the following compile error.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/gtaskos/Documents/Projects/My/SDKs/My iOS SDK/My-iOS/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/gtaskos/Documents/Projects/My/SDKs/My iOS SDK/My-iOS/Frameworks/GHUnitIOS.framework/GHUnitIOS, missing required architecture arm64 in file /Users/gtaskos/Documents/Projects/My/SDKs/My iOS SDK/My-iOS/Frameworks/GHUnitIOS.framework/GHUnitIOS (4 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GHAsyncTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MyMintTests in MyMintTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GHAsyncTestCase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_MyMintTests in MyMintTests.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GHTesting", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MyMintTests.o
  "_GHComposeString", referenced from:
      ___38-[MyMintTests testGetDetailsAsync]_block_invoke in MyMintTests.o
      ___38-[MyMintTests testGetDetailsAsync]_block_invoke38 in MyMintTests.o
      -[MyMintTests testStrings] in MyMintTests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Strange is I tried the `https://github.com/gh-unit/gh-unit/tree/master/Examples/MyTestable-iOS` and it works pretty fine.

Some configuration/setup. I have a workspace with a static library project that uses pods for a dependency, in that project I have a OCUnit tests target, a framework aggregate and added an Empty Application target that configured to use GHUnit, added the framework and used the `GHUnitIOSAppDelegate` in the `main.cs`.

Then I added an Objective-C class with a custom name MyMintGHUnitTests.m which has some methods (although only testStrings is available when I run the target, that is another question for StackOverflow).

```
- (void) testGetDetailsAsync
    {
    // Call prepare to setup the asynchronous action.
    // This helps in cases where the action is synchronous and the
    // action occurs before the wait is actually called.
    [self prepare];

    [self.utility getDetailsNumWithBlock:^(NSNumber *total)
        {
        GHTestLog(@"Details Number: %@", total);
        GHAssertNotNil(totalCrashes, nil);
        [self notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess forSelector:@selector(getDetailsAsyncTest)];
        }
    failure:^(NSError *error)
        {
        GHTestLog(@"Failed to get details: %@", error.description);
        GHAssertNil(error, nil);
        [self notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess forSelector:@selector(getDetailsAsyncTest)];
        }];

    // Wait until notify called for timeout (seconds); If notify is not called with kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess then
    // we will throw an error.
    [self waitForStatus:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess timeout:5.0];
    }
```

Class inherits from `GHAsyncTestCase`.

Maybe I should say that I also use pods for the GHUnit target.

The target runs on Simulator (without my methods) perfect fails on device.